# Extracting frequencies with Fourier transformation

Tags: fourier-analysis

I know this question came up so many times, but after browsing through many of the threads, I'm still not sure, if I'm doing it correctly with my dataset, so I'll give it a try.

If have some sample data I know not much about. You can download it [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19921198/testdata.txt)

[image]

Now I want to look for possible dominant frequencies and it tried it like this:

```
ListLinePlot[Log[10, Abs[Fourier[data]]], PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

and I get this:

[image]

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see any dominant frequencies in here. Do you guys come to the same conclusion? Honestly, I think I'm doing it all wrong because I'm really not sure which of the many functions of mathematica to use.

EDIT: Now I'm totally confused. I just looked again in some of my books and what they did there was drawing the frequencies on the x-Axes and the Power on the y-Axes. Then they normalised it to the total power. How to do this?

Comment: What was the sampling frequency?

Comment: @Nasser: It's data from an fMRI scan. So a scan was done every 2800 ms. Sorry, I'm just trying to get more into this stuff :/

Comment: Ok, so fs=0.357 hz? (1/2.8)

Comment: btw, this looks like a very low sample rate. You can adjust the code below if you think it is different. 0.357 samples per second is very low but you can check it on your end. If you meant it was 2800 samples per second, then change `fs` below to 2800.

Comment: I'm not really sure, but every 2,8 sec a scan was done, i.e. data was collected..so the sampling rate must be 2,8 sec?

Comment: If you say so. I do not know about fMRI. But one sample each 2.8 seconds sounds too slow to me. any way, you can change that later if you find otherwise. change `fs` below, which is the sample rate of the data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming sample rate is 2.8 second per sample, then may be this:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
data = Import["testdata.txt", "List"];
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
py = Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];  
nSamples = Length[data];
nUniquePts = Ceiling[(nSamples + 1)/2];
py = py[[1 ;; nUniquePts]];
py = Abs[py];
py[[1]] = 0;  (*zero out the DC frequency, for now, outliner, messes up the scale *)
py = py/nSamples;
py = py^2;
If[OddQ[nSamples], py[[2 ;; -1]] = 2*py[[2 ;; -1]], py[[2 ;; -2]] = 2*py[[2 ;; -2]]];
fs = 0.357;  (*2.8 second per sample*)
f = (Range[0, nUniquePts - 1] fs)/nSamples;
ListPlot[Transpose[{f, py}], Joined -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"|H(f)|", None}, {"hz", "Magnitude spectrum"}}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, RotateLabel -> False, 
    GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Dashed, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above is the magnitude spectrum. So you can see now where the frequencies with most energy are.

Comment: Quick question: Is all this method with `py` and `nUniquePts` a commonly used thing?

Comment: @Öskå  I do not know if it very commonly used t, but I use this method all the time. In Matlab some use this method. http://localhost/my_notes/mma_matlab_control/KERNEL/KEse52.htm#x60-5900052

Comment: Thank you @Nasser! Why is it that you did not use Fourier or some similar function? I mean..where is the fouriertransform in all this?

Comment: I guess "localhost" has to be replaced by "12000.org" :)

Comment: @Öskå opps, yes sorry

Comment: @holistic I used Fourier ofcourse, I just forgot to paste the command since it was in separate cell. Updated now, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the link! I have always wondered how to extract dominant frequencies from a set of data.

Comment: hmm @Nasser: somehow it doesn't work in my notebook. I just copied your code: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-22153563/code.png.html

Any idea why?

Comment: @holistic You need to do `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
data = Import["testdata.txt", "List"];` as shown. This reads the data. Make sure your file `testdata.txt` is in the same folder where the notebook is saved to.  Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/l7uON.png) and  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gFX75.png)  it works for me. May be you changed your data or something.

Comment: @Nasser: This is really weird. I checked it several times and did all you said, but it still doesn't work: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-22153646/code.png.html

it reads the data just fine though. I checked every single row: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-22153686/code2.png.html

Comment: @holistic give me few minutes to look at it again

Comment: @Nasser: No problem. My mathematica version is 9.0.1.0 btw. Here is the version with 2800 sampling rate: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-22153786/code3.png.html
. I seem to have a totally different scale in the ListPlot like you.

Comment: @holistic Please try the new code. It is was something I did before and forgot to refresh the session. Needed to zero out the DC frequency. For some reason, it was an outliner, hence it messed up the scale. I updated the code above.

Comment: @Nasser: Works perfect now, thank you very much!  http://www.pic-upload.de/view-22153833/Fourier_tests.jpg.html

Quick question: Is this example normalized to the total power? If not, how would you do it? I assume I have to divide every point by the total power, but I didn't totally understand the code yet (takes some time), so I have no idea how to implement it atm :)

Comment: @holistic if you mean the `py/nSamples` then this is something commonly done, to average the power. Its been a while since I did dsp, so I do not remember the details now. But the above is a common way to do it (scale the psd by number of samples).

Comment: @Nasser: I guess you're right. Thanks again!